# How to access child's onClick in React.Fragment

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am very new to react and JavaScript and this is my second week of react learning. I am now stuck with the event propagation problem. I have tried to access onClick in the child of <React.Fragment> but event target is seem to be in <React.Fragment> itself. I can not find the simple solution. Please help, Thank you very much in advance.

```
return (
    {loading ? ("...loading...") : data.map(({id,project_title,project_subtitle, project_description,image_url,link},index) => (
                  <React.Fragment>
                    <ProjectListButton  onClick={(e)=>{ alert(index)}}  id={"b"+id} project_title={project_title} project_subtitle={project_subtitle} />
                    <ProjectPlate project_description = {project_description} image_url ={image_url} link ={link} />
                  </React.Fragment>
                )
              )
            }
)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @YaakovAinspan I try to access onClick in <ProjectListButton/> but it stuck in <React.Fragment>

Answer (score -1):

```
<React.Fragment>
```

is wrapper, to wrap the html elements or sibling elements. It acts as a sudo parent and it just wraps them.

We can't add any attributes to the react fragment.

If you want to capture events, replace fragments with `div` and add a listener on it. It is not required to use `fragment`. It is just an option to save an extra element, if we just need them for wrapping purpose.